# Is it okay to write $\ln^2(x)$ or $\ln(x)^2$ instead of $(\ln(x))^2$?

Tags: functions, notation

In most places, by convention one can write $\cos^2{x}$ to mean $(\cos(x))^2=\cos(x) \cdot \cos(x)$. Calculators additionally usually interpret $\cos(x)^2$ as $\cos^2(x)$, though as far as I can tell, this way is disliked by many mathematicians, as it implies $\cos(x^2)$, which is something completely different.

My question is, how valid are the following representations of $(\ln(x))^2$?

$$\ln^2x$$
$$\ln^2(x)$$
$$\ln(x)^2$$

What about for other (trigonometric) functions, or just functions $f(x)$ in general?

$$f^2x$$ 
$$f^2(x)$$
$$f(x)^2$$

Comment: The representations of $ln$ are all valid, although the last one looks weird.  I would also not write $f^2x$ without parenthesees.  Note that $cos^2(x) \not= cos(x^2)$!!!

Comment: and also $$\ln(x^2)\ne \ln(x)^2$$

Comment: @Dubstep365 Sorry, I missed a word and it seemed like I thought it was correct. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner that's interesting. What does the latter mean then?

Comment: Yes choosing the notation for something as simple as $(\ln (2(x+1)))^2$ is a pitty, so depending on the context choose the one you prefer, and make it clear that $\ln \ln x \ne \ln^2 x \ne \ln x^2$

Comment: It seems the 'correct way' must be $\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]^{2}$: You are squaring the value of  $\ln\left(x\right)$. However, for simplicity, it's usually written as the shortcut $\ln^{2}\left(x\right)$ albeit rigorously it should be $\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Okay... what I want to write is $\ln(x)\ln(x)$. But you're saying that $\ln^2(x)$ is $\ln(\ln(x))$? That something completely different, though...

Comment: @SkeletonBow $\large\texttt{NO}$. It's usual to write $\ln^{2}\left(x\right)$ which $\underline{means}$ $\ln\left(x\right)\ln\left(x\right)$. In another post (I dont' remember), a mathematician said that rigorously it means
$\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)$ albeit people uses $\ln^{2}\left(x\right)$ as a shorcut for $\ln\left(x\right)\ln\left(x\right)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Wow okay chill out. Thanks for explaining, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all functions in general, $f^2(x)$ is the one that I will prefer and suggest to you. $f^2x$ is also equivalently correct but the parenthesis around $x$ look better. However, the notation $f(x)^2$ is a bit confusing as to what is being squared - the function $f$ or the variable $x$. So, to use this notation, you need to use curly brackets around $f$, like $\{f(x)\}^2$.

Similarly, in accordance to the above mentioned details, $\ln^2(x)$ is the most correct notation followed by $\ln^2x$ while the notation $\ln(x)^2$ is confusing and I would dub it wrong.

Addendum:  As per guestDiego's comment,

> Maybe a caveat is necessary here: in many contests
>   $f^2(x)=(f∘f)(x)=f(f(x))$. This is not the case of
>   $\ln$ and $\sin$,$\cos$ essentially for an established traditional use,
>   so normally $\sin^2(x)=(\sin(x))^2$. In other cases I
>   would be cautious even in using this notation. Of course the totally
>   non ambiguous notation is $(f(x))^2$. Unfortunately it is more
>   costly.

Comment: Maybe a caveat is necessary here: in many contests $f^2(x)=(f\circ f)(x)=f(f(x))$. This is not the case of $\ln$ and $\sin,\cos$ essentially  for  an established traditional use, so normally $\sin^2(x)=(\sin (x))^2$. In other cases I would be cautious even in using this notation. Of course the totally non ambiguous notation is $(f(x))^2$. Unfortunatly it is more costly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just as a follow up, using this logic, would it be okay to write $\text{cis}^2{\pi}$ to mean the square of $\text{cis}(\pi)$ (the polar form of $-1$)?

Comment: @guestDiego This is a very useful piece of additional information!

Comment: @guestDiego I totally buy your argument, but it is also a bit non-traditional or rather non-conventional. So I am adding your comment as an addendum to my post.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Ok, thank you.

Comment: @SkeletonBow An extremely unusual notation, I must say ... I have never seen anything like $\mathrm{cis} ^2 \pi$ ... Anyways, it means exactly what you have guessed. That's what I think.

Comment: @SkeletonBow. Well, I agree with SchrodingersCat that $f^2=f\circ f$ is unconventional (in a calculus context at least). So I guess that your notation for $\textrm{cis}$ is acceptable. Of course the notation $ f^2=f \circ f$ is conventional in other contexts (in set theory, but also others algebra-oriented)

Comment: I fail to see how $f(x)^2$ can be parsed as anything but the square of $f(x)$. The parentheses in the function notation have a stronger meaning than just grouping together terms

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Several times, it has been observed that $f(x)^2$ has been printed or produced as a typo in place of $f(x^2)$. In cases where it is meant to be the square of $f(x)$, the use of curly brackets is a common notion. Well that's what I have seen till date.. However there may be texts where they use the notation $f(x)^2$ with enough prominence.. I don't want to be dragged into that controversy.

Comment: The thing is that it is not really controversial as far as I can tell. The only argument I have so far seen against it is that it might have been a typo, but so might any number of other things.

Answer (score 1):

From the existence of $\LaTeX$ it is very common in books or papers write $f(x)^2$ as a way to write $(f(x))^2$.

The use of $f^2(x)$ is totally deprecated nowadays due to aesthetics reasons of the render of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Since ~2000 every scientific books and papers are written in $\LaTeX$ ?